# Passing a placeholder string when filter condition not met

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to pass an email address appended to the end of the file to a different table. However, I would like to enter a placeholder value if no email address is present in the file.

I have a router transformation that checks for '@' in the file, like this:

```
INSTR(UPPER(ITEM_VALUE),'@')>0
```

Is there any way to pass a placeholder value in the table when no email address is present in the file?

Comment: can you pls give more details ? your condition will detect @ in the text. So, if data has @ it will go through the router. you can keep a long string as placeholder. If you want to check and validate if a string is email or not you can use - https://network.informatica.com/thread/38510

Comment: We have a column 'ITEM_VALUE' in which some values come from a source. These values need to be loaded to Table_A. At the end of the file, there is an email address, say, abc@xyz.com, which need to be loaded to Table_B and an email needs to be sent confirming data load. However, in many cases, we don't get an email at the end of the file, due to which data load fails. I want to add a placeholder email address (def@xyz.com) whenever we don't get an email address. Currently, I'm using router transformation to route the data in 2 different tables using condition specified above.

Comment: can you use this kind of defaulting logic `IIF (INSTR(UPPER(ITEM_VALUE),'@')>0, email_from file, 'defaultemail@xyz.com' )` you can store all data into one single table.

Comment: Unfortunately, Table_A is the data table, and Table_B logs the source email for audit purposes. Both data can't be loaded to the same table. Also, number of columns in both tables are different.

Comment: ok, can you use above logic then to default the mail id when absent?

Comment: Koushik gave the condition - I'd just add that UPPER makes no sense if looking for "@", so we can simplify it to `IIF (INSTR(ITEM_VALUE,'@')>0, email_from_file, 'defaultemail@xyz.com' )`